# Is there a work around for adding the '.active' class to the first slide of a Bootstrap 4 Carousel?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am implementing a [Bootstrap 4 Carousel](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/#via-data-attributes) on my site and have come up against a problem:

The Carousel seems to need the `.active` class to be set on the first slide otherwise it wont work. With the way I've implemented the Carousel in my CMS, I've used a single template file for the slide (with dynamic content within), allowing me to implement an unlimited number of slides. However, I cannot set the initial slide to have the `.active` class without that class appearing on all of them, and breaking the carousel.

I could use some JQuery to add that class to the first instance of a slide, but I'm hoping there's a way around this (to me it seems a bit of an oversight of Bootstrap).

Would anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: What language are you for your CMS? Why can you not code in a condition to add the active class for the first slide?

Comment: I could, but want to avoid stuff like that if there's a proper Bootstrap way of doing this that I'm not aware of.

Comment: @MeltingDog  add that to the HTML directly.That's the only way to do it(without any extra bit of unnecessary coding)

Comment: Seems like the code in the CMS should be creating the proper Bootstrap way and adding active to just the first slide. I am sure that you have a loop for adding the slides and all you need to add is an if slide = 1 add the active class.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jquery to add class active. this will solve the issue

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#myCarousel').find('.item').first().addClass('active');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Carousel Example</h2>  
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://cableandmedia.com/pnnm/assets/images/hospital/hos6.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://cableandmedia.com/pnnm/assets/images/hospital/hos4.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
    
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://cableandmedia.com/pnnm/assets/images/hospital/hos7.jpg" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yep thats what I ended up doing. Just wasnt sure if BS4 had a way of doing this already